# Jquery spinner first click value

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

I have a jquery spinner with the following js

```
  $(function() { 
    $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
      min: 0,
      max: 300,
      step: 10
    });
  });
```

I need to the spinner value jump from 0 to 50 in first click. Or in other words i need values to to be 0,50,60,70,80 etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No one can say without knowing what the `spinner()` function actually does, but my money is on changing the value of the `step` property to 50.

Update: No, just realized you're only gunning for the first step. Check the config options for the spinner function. If individual steps can't be changed, you may need to wrap the spinner function in your own function with the additional functionality.

Comment: Would it be possible with the spinner pageUp method? http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/spinner/#method-pageUp Any advice on how it could be?